# .htaccess rewriterule giving error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^Buy\-(.*)-b(.*)\.html productdetails.php?bname=$1&bid=$2
```

The above code in .htaccess works fine if the $bname = "Time to go shopping" or $bname = "Time to go: shopping". and gives the following link
http://www.yourdomain.com/Buy-Time to go shopping-b1.html
or
http://www.yourdomain.com/Buy-Time to go: shopping-b1.html

But if $bname = "Time: to go shopping" the above gives a bad link.
buy-time: to go shopping-b1.html

Comment: ahh that was a typo i forgot to type -b1 suffix in the last link in my question . It is there originally. And on clicking the link it says bad link

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your problem is just the case of the `Buy-` in the regex vs `buy-` in the next URL. If so, then you just need the no-case `[NC]` flag:

```
 RewriteRule  ^Buy\-(.*)-b(\d+)\.html  ...?bname=$1&bid=$2  [NC]
```

I took the liberty to also add the `\d+` for specificity.

Comment: I suspect your problem description is off. Try enabling the `RewriteLog` to find out the source of your issues.

Comment: I am new to this so how do i do that? Just put RewriteLog in .htaccess or type RewriteLog on in .htaccess. Both methods give 500 Internal Server Error on any page which was using RewriteRule be the one mentioned above or anyother